# Index 0 of array is undefined after someEmptyArray.push(data)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, undefined

I am running `fs.readdir` to return an array of the filenames in a directory. I am running some regex functions to filter out certain  filenames and/or filetypes that I don't want displayed.

With the following code I have returned a new filtered array, but the array's 0 index is returning undefined.

Sorry in advance for the code formatting, I'm on my cell phone and I don't have access to a computer with internet.

```
fs.readdir('./schema', function(err,files){
  var filelist = [];
  if(err)
    throw err;
  else{
    var index = files.length;
    while(index>0){
      filelist.push(isNOTswapfile(files[index]));
      index--;
      }
    console.log(filelist)
    }
  }
)
```

This returns `[undefined, 'file_1.js']
Why is this happening and how do I get rid of it?

Thanks

Comment: Put `index--` before `push`.

Comment: Or change this  var index = files.length  to  var index = files.length -1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`files[index]` the first time is `undefined` since the length of an array will always be greater than the biggest index (zero based indexes). Move `index--` one line up, and it will work, however you'll be leaving out the first element, so compare to `>=0` or index-1 to get all elements.

```
fs.readdir('./schema', function(err, files) {
    var filelist = [];
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        var index = files.length;
        while (index >= 0) {
            index--;
            filelist.push(isNOTswapfile(files[index]));
        }
        console.log(filelist)
    }
})
```

Comment: I prefer using `0>=` in the `while` loop for readability, but it's not working. Though files[index-1] worked. Thanks!